# How can I turn off log level & category output in .NET Core logging to AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-cloudwatch

I have setup my API and Console Application to send logs to CloudWatch via NuGet package `Aws.Logging.AspNetCore`.

I can successfully see the logs in CloudWatch but by default it came with unwanted information:

```
[Trace] Infra.AwsLogger: 
{
    "id": "AAA",
    "timestamp": "timestamp",
    "logLevel": "Trace",
    "message": "my message"
}
```

I do not want the `[Trace] Infra.AwsLogger:`  part, all I wanted to log is the JSON

```
{
    "id": "AAA",
    "timestamp": "timestamp",
    "logLevel": "Trace",
    "message": "my message"
}
```

Here is my logger code:

```
public class AwsLogger : IAwsLogger
{
        private readonly AwsLoggerOptions _awsLoggerOptions;
        private readonly LoggerFactory _logFactory;
        private ILogger _logger;

        public AwsLogger(IOptions<AwsLoggerOptions> awsLoggerOptions)
        {
            _awsLoggerOptions = awsLoggerOptions?.Value;

            var loggerConfig = new AWSLoggerConfig
            {
                LogGroup = _awsLoggerOptions?.LogGroup,
                Region = _awsLoggerOptions?.Region
            };

            _logFactory = new LoggerFactory();
            _logFactory.AddAWSProvider(loggerConfig);
        }

        public void Log(LogMessage message, LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            _logger = _logFactory.CreateLogger<AwsLogger>();

            logMessage.LogLevel = logLevel;

            var logMessageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

            switch (logLevel)
            {
                case Information:
                    _logger.LogInformation(logMessageString);
                    break;
                case .Warning:
                    _logger.LogWarning(logMessageString);
                    break;
                case Error:
                    _logger.LogError(logMessageString);
                    break;
                case Trace:
                    _logger.LogTrace(logMessageString);
                    break;
                case Debug:
                    _logger.LogDebug(logMessageString);
                    break;
                default:
                    _logger.LogInformation(logMessageString);
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

Here is my appsettings:

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeLogLevel": false,
    "IncludeCategory": false,
    "IncludeNewline": false,
    "IncludeException": false,
    "IncludeEventId": false,
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Region": "region",
    "LogGroup": "loggroup",
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is structured logging. Serilog is one structured logging framework. You can use AWS.Logger.SeriLog nuget package to push the structured logs to AWS.

You can use the below references to configure one.

https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet#aspnet-core-logging

https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics

For Json format you can use "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog" formatter.

Comment: Thank you I will try on that! Does Serilog supports logging into specific log stream to CloudWatch as well?

Comment: Yes. You can find all the information https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet#aspnet-core-logging.  The way serilog works is, it uses a concept of the sink to push data to different stores. In your case its AWS cloudwatch logs.